# Arduino NodeMCU POST not working

Tags: php, post, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

I have a `NodeMCU 1.0` with `ESP-12E` on it and using Arduino IDE for writing code on it.

I want to send a `POST` message to a remote `php` page on my webserer containing values from my module, but firstly I need to send something...

I tried many different examples from different sources and code snippets, but none seem to work. The method it's being sent 
The `GET` method it's working, I can retrieve data from php pages, but I cannot send to them.

My code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>

const char* ssid     = "SomeWireless";
const char* password = "12345";

String server = "www.example.net"; // www.example.com

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
 // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");  
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

}

void loop() {
  jsonPOST();
  myPOST();
  myGET();
}


void myPOST() {
  HTTPClient http;

  http.begin("http://example.net/asd/recv.php");
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  http.POST("title=foo");
  http.writeToStream(&Serial);
  http.end();

  delay(1000);
}

void jsonPOST() {
  WiFiClient client;

  if (client.connect("example.net", 80)) {
      Serial.println("Connected to server");
  // Make the HTTP request
      int value = 2.5;  // an arbitrary value for testing
      String content = "{\"JSON_key\": " + String(value) + "}";
      client.println("POST /asd/recv.php HTTP/1.1");
      client.println("Host: example.net");
      client.println("Accept: */*");
      client.println("Content-Length: " + String(content.length()));
      client.println("Content-Type: application/json");
      client.println();
      client.println(content);
  }
  delay(1000);
}

void myGET() {
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) { //Check     WiFi connection status
    HTTPClient http;  //Declare an object of class HTTPClient
    http.begin("http://www.exmaple.net/asd/btnCheck.php");  //Specify request destination
    int httpCode = http.GET();  //Send the request

    if (httpCode > 0) { //Check the returning code
      String payload = http.getString();   //Get the request response payload
      Serial.println(payload);                     //Print the response payload
    }
    http.end();   //Close connection
  }
  delay(1000); 
}
```

My php:

```
$test = $_POST['title'];
echo $test;

//JSON
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj;
```

**EDIT :** I want to mention that the web server can accept POST messages and also that I have a reseller type of account, so I don't have full control of the server.

Any advice on this matter, it's worth it. I've been beating my head with it, for 2 days.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER:**

I manage to do the request properly. The problem was from my post content.
The code that works for me with the `ESP8266HTTPClient.h` library is:

```
void jPOST() {
  HTTPClient http;

  http.begin("http://example.net/asd/urlen.php");
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  http.POST("{\"y\":6,\"x\":11}");
  http.writeToStream(&Serial);
  http.end();

  delay(2000);
}
```

And for the php page:

```
$req1 = file_get_contents("php://input");
$req2 = json_decode($req1);

$val= $req2 ->x;
echo $val;
//echo $req2 -> x;

mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO tbl_ard(field1) VALUES($val)");
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection in `$val`, which is dangerous.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of it, just wanted to receive the message ^^.